# AngularJS Directive ng-repeat first time element shown

Tags: angularjs

I want to apply a custom directive in a ng-repeat on an html element the first time it appears.  All further elements after the first appearance would not have the directive or the directive would not be enabled.

The element may not appear on the first iteration of the ng-repeat so I can't use $first.

I'm creating a tutorial tooltip and want it to only show on the first visible element.  The underlying scope of the ng-repeat has no knowledge of the tutorial so I can't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can write a directive like this -

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])

app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.done = false;
    $scope.items = [{
      name: 'One'
    }, {
      name: 'Two'
    }, {
      name: 'Three',
      special: true
    }, {
      name: 'Four',
      special: true
    }, {
      name: 'Five',
      special: true
    }];
  }
]);

app.directive('special', function() {
  return {
    scope: false,
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if (scope.item.special && !scope.$parent.$parent.done) {
        scope.done = true;
        scope.$parent.$parent.done = true;
      }
    },
    template: "<p ng-class='{active: item.special && this.done}'>{{ item.name }}</p>"
  };
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="HomeCtrl">

  <li ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" special="" item="item" done="done">{{ item.name }}</li>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**UPDATE**

> So, phew! I got it to work but if you look at the directive you'll see that I'm playing around with the parent scopes using the $parent attribute.. I don't have a better solution for now. :(

Hope that helped!

Comment: The issue I've got is Four may also have special = true and I only want the directive to apply for Three.

Comment: @DaveBarker Solved it but I'm not sure if it's the best solution though.